# Angular - Firebase : Not able to transform a set method into a push method

Tags: angular, firebase

In an Angular project, I have an User model :

```
export class User {
  constructor (public idUser:string,
              public firstName: string,
              public lastName:string,
              public email:string,
              public ptsJournee:number,
              public ptsTotal:number){}
}
```

I created a Service called Users to manage users of my website.
Initially, I was using a set method to save new Users:

```
  users: User[] = [];
  usersSubject = new Subject<User[]>();

emitUsers(){
    this.usersSubject.next(this.users);
  }

saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').set(this.users);
  }

getUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users')
    .on('value',(data)=>{
      this.users = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
      this.emitUsers();
    });
  }

createNewProfile(newUser:User){
    this.getUsers();
    this.users.push(newUser);
    this.saveUsers();
    this.emitUsers();
  }
```

Now, I want to use a push method to save my user (in order to get a unique Id):

```
saveUsers(){
    firebase.database().ref('/users').push(this.users);
  }
```

But when I want to display my users with a NgFor. It's not working with the error : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. . Could you say me what I'm not doing ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the Firebase database, but the error means you are trying to iterate over an object. In which case you could use the `keyvalue` pipe with `*ngFor` directive.

Comment: I'm not able to get {{user.lastName}} but I don't have the error anymore / The thing is that it's working perfectly with the set method even without the Pipe```<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <div class="list-group"
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let user of users | keyvalue">
        <p>{{user.lastName}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `batch` method instead of set, since you're trying to create multiple documents.

Iterate over (`forEach` or similar) the Users Array and for each user set a document - similar to below:

```
saveUsers(users: Users[]) {
    const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();

    users.ForEach(users => {
        const uid = user.id;

        const userDocRef = 
            firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`);

            // Optionally 'merge' the document or leav eout to replace the document
            batch.set(userDocRef , { ...user }, { merge: true });
    });

    return batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I just want to create a database with my users and I know that push permit to get an unique ID. That's why I would like to use that method.

Comment: I think what you want to do is create a document for each user, which would be a batch or transaction operation. What the above does is creates a set operation for each user and adds the documents to the users collection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my main problem is my getUsers() method that is not returning data with a good format.

When I use push, I can see data in my database.

It's my first development project, I'm not sure to understand everything.